# Загрузил файлы php из локального компьютера в сервер, домен и хостинг купил. Не работает страница авторизации и регистрации, почему?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Купил хостинг и домен. Загрузил файлы php протестированные из локального сервера WP, также импортировал таблицу. Вот сам сайт http://silksroads.uz, куда были загружены php файлы. Ошибок не выдает, зависает на странице регистрации и авторизации, а в локальном сервере всё работает отлично. Также в браузере IE вообще не входит в авторизацию, контент бегает при навигации в боковой панели. В мозиле также не проходит авторизация. В опере не проверял, т.к. браузера нет в моём компьютере.
В чём дело, может дело в версии БД и php на сервере?

Comment: Смотри логи на сервере, там всё написано

Comment: Куча ошибок в отладчике. Проверьте правильность путей к скриптам относительно текущего хостинга. Такое бывает, когда например путь к скрипту http://localhost/script.js, а надо http://webdomain.com/script.js

Comment: Отладчик красненький... Может оттуда начать поиск? По крайней мере php инициирует запросы с результатом 404.. Файл maine.js  вообще не подтягивается, Jquery запрашивается по нескольким путям.. Путей там много неисповедимых..

Comment: ispmanager с ним не работал. Куда тыкать, где искать?

Comment: Хм, silk road... Это те, которые торговали запрещенными товарами?

Comment: Это совсем другая компания и другой клиент. Они связаны с торговлей, как мне известно всё под контролем самого владельца. Запрещённые товары не будут продаваться из-за ограничений со стороны налоговой службы. Налоговые службы прикрепили коды товаров, без которых владелец не сможет сдать отчёт, если будут проданы запрещённые товары. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях проблема может быть сильно разбросана, так как похожее поведение вызывают разные проблемы. Но вот вам несколько советов:

1. Хостинги не всегда дают вам называть вашу базу данных как вы хотите, часто это ваш логин _ и желаемое имя бд. Вам следует проверить чтобы в php подключение к бд были правильными для хостинга
2. Версия БД и PHP, PHP старых версий могут не поддерживать некоторые методы или функции, или иметь другое написание (например mysqli_query вместо mysql_query из PHP 5.0), убедитесь что загружаемый PHP написан на PHP хостинга. Часто вам дают возможность выбрать версию PHP на хостинге, тогда вам следует настроить всё правильно
3. Форма может отображаться не правильно особенно в IE когда используются стили которые он не поддерживает.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил в коде некоторые команды. Действительно оказалось у меня старая версия php 7. Также помогло изменение доступ к БД, права были не полными.